# How can I set a cookie and then redirect in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers

After doing a bit of processing, I want to set a cookie value to user input and then redirect them to a new page.  However, the cookie is not getting set.  If I comment out the redirect, then the cookie is set successfully.  I assume this is a header issue of some sort.  What is the best workaround for this situation?

```
if($form_submitted) {
    ...
    setcookie('type_id', $new_type_id, time() + 60*60*24*30);
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

Note that setcookie returns `true` in either case and I get no errors/warnings/notices.

**EDIT:** I am using Unix/Apache/MySQL/PHP

Comment: Did you try settings the cookie after the header()?

Comment: sikx - The cookie does not get set either if I use header() first.

Comment: I had a problem where `Location: http://domain.com/asd` wouldn't save the cookie. Doing `Location: /asd` solved it for me.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you have human-readable urls or subfolders (like [www.domain.com/path1/path2/](http://www.domain.com/path1/path2/)), then you must set cookie path to / to work for all paths, not just current one.

```
if($form_submitted) {
    ...
    setcookie('type_id', $new_type_id, time() + 60*60*24*30, '/');
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

From PHP manual:

> The path on the server in which the
> cookie will be available on. If set to
> '/', the cookie will be available
> within the entire domain . If set to
> '/foo/', the cookie will only be
> available within the /foo/ directory
> and all sub-directories such as
> /foo/bar/ of domain . The default
> value is the current directory that
> the cookie is being set in.

Comment: Then you should have asked the @QuestionMark.

Answer (score 4):

How are you testing if the cookie is set?  Cookies are available on the *next* page after they are set.

> Common Pitfalls:
>
> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling print_r($_COOKIE);.

Comment: I was checking whether the cookie was set through a browser plugin.  Even if I then navigate to another page and check my cookies, it is not set.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you are running IIS? There is a know bug with IIS versions less than 7 when attempting to both set a cookie and a location header in the same request.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q176113/

Comment: I'm using IIS and hit this exact problem. Do you know a workaround in a .php script ?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this problem by using a slight delay in the refresh header. We set the header (which must be done before any methods which might output, like setcookie), and then set the cookies. I added a message so that the user doesn't see a blank screen for those couple seconds.

```
    header("refresh: 2; url=$url");
    setcookie('type_id', $new_type_id, time() + 60*60*24*30, '/');
    echo "Processing, please wait...";
```

Comment: it's the echo that causes this to work, not the header. You're sending a response to the browser, which causes the cookie to also be sent. just setting the cookie then redirecting doesn't do a 302 status to the browser, it just transfers processing server side, so the client never know about the cookie.

Comment: @frumbert "just setting the cookie then redirecting doesn't do a 302 status to the browser" - yes it does. "it just transfers processing server side" - no it doesn't. (?) This question already has an accepted answer which does just that (which does work).

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative URL in the header:

```
@Header("Location: orders_9090_1.php");
```

Comment: Dude, remove that @ please, it must be banned from coding. If a function tells you a message, read it, understand it, solve it. Not "hide it".

Answer (score 0):

I have made solution for that

```
    setcookie(self::SESSION_NAME, $session_id, $expires, '/', null, null, true);
    header("Set-cookie: ".self::SESSION_NAME."=".$session_id."; expires=".date('D, Y-M-d H:i:s', $expires)." GMT; path=/; HttpOnly; secure=true; SameSite=Strict");
    
//check is something printed
    if (!headers_sent()) {
    
//is there any header set
                if( !array_map(function($header){ return preg_match('/Set-cookie/i', $header) ? true : null; }, headers_list()) ){
    
                    die(header('Location: ' . $url));
                }
            }
            die('<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = ' . ($append ? 'window.location.href' : '') . ($append && $url ? '+' : '') . ($url ? '"' . $url . '"' : '') . ';</script>');
```