# can't set cookie correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

Site built on Code Igniter framework. I have two links (like and dislike). When you click the link, the correspond value increases or decreases. You can see the site: http://joke.guluzade.com/jokes/view/24

What I want: That user can change this value only once. I do it by cookies. For example, if user click to "like" link the value +5 became +6. Then if you click "dislike" the value must not change. User should have only one chance to like or dislike. Now it doesn't work correctly, if you click like you are able to click dislike too, but I want only change the lie or dislike value only one time.

How I do: I check if the cookie is set, function does nothing, if not it sets cookie and changes value. But if cookie set for like, when you click dislike it doesn't see that cookie.

Here is code:

```
function vote ($mm, $id){ //get the parameters (like or dislike and id)
    $name = $mm;
    $value = (int)$id;
    $time = time()+3600;
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$value])){
            redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    } else {
        SetCookie($value, $name, $time);
        if($name == "like"){
            $this->db->select('like');
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $query = $this->db->get('jokes');
            $data = $query->row_array();
            $likes = $data['like'];
            $likes++;
            $dd = array();
            $dd['like'] = $likes;        
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->update('jokes', $dd);
            redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);                 
        } else {
            $this->db->select('dislike');
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $query = $this->db->get('jokes');
            $data = $query->row_array();
            $likes = $data['dislike'];
            $likes--;
            $dd = array();
            $dd['dislike'] = $likes;
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->update('jokes', $dd);   
            redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);               
        }    
    }
}
```

Can anybody say, what I do wrong?

Comment: check if this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612034/how-can-i-set-a-cookie-and-then-redirect-in-php

Comment: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1509045

Comment: @Chinook Should post his comment as answer so the OP could accept it.

Answer (score 2):

use get_cookie('some_cookie') OR get_cookie('some_cookie',TRUE); instead of $cookie[$value].

moreover set cookie for full domain using

```
                $cookie = array(
               'name'   => 'The Cookie Name',
               'value'  => 'The Value',
               'expire' => '86500',
               'domain' => '.some-domain.com',
               'path'   => '/',

                );

               set_cookie($cookie);
```

Comment: I have already solved it. The issue was on path, I added the path '/' and it worked right.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer from following posts.

[How can I set a cookie and then redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612034/how-can-i-set-a-cookie-and-then-redirect-in-php)

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1509045

Comment: I found an answer. Read the comments to question