# Cookies do not work in PHP but do work Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I need to see the cart of products, and I need to do a first load by PHP and the rest of queries (updates by deleting a product or similar) by jQuery post.

Ok, there's the problem.

[*I get variables by JSON on the same php file "any.php"*]

The first PHP load doesn't work , when I do the first `isset($_COOKIE)` on PHP (by curl) and returns NULL, but.. if I call the method `.post("any.php")` on jQuery PHP, it returns the cart with products.

For add the products I use PHP function

```php
setcookie($cookieName, $createcart, $cookieExpire);
```

Cookie Params:

```php
session_set_cookie_params(
    time()+3600,
    '/',
    '.test.com',
    0,
    0
);
```

setCookie (createcart is the json value):

```php
setcookie($cookieName, $createcart, $cookieExpire);
```

**PHPINFO**

```php
session

Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   .test.com.pe    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 1379499657  0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php/session    /var/lib/php/session
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using it right? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php `Thus, you need to call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and before session_start() is called.`

Comment: ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.test.com.pe');
 ini_set("session.use_cookies", 1);
session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params(
 time()+3600,
 '/',
 '.test.com.pe',
 FALSE,
 FALSE
);
session_start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

> Common Pitfalls:
>
> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that
>   the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully
>   set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie
>   expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to
>   debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling
>   print_r($_COOKIE);.

See also: [How can I set a cookie and then redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612034/how-can-i-set-a-cookie-and-then-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the path of the cookie. You need write it for work correcly in the whole pages.

### path

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php