# Cookie wont set, no result

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

```
$cookie_name = "login";
$cookie_value = "True";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value);
header("Location: http://Startseite.php");
exit;
```

#And this is on "Startseite.php"

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['login']))
   echo "login erfolgreich"
```

The Echo dont give a Result. This says that my cookie is not set.I tried it with more Values, but with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever tried this?

> If you have human urls or subfolders (like www.domain.com/path1/path2/), then you must set cookie path to / to work for all paths, not just current one.

[How can I set a cookie and then redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612034/how-can-i-set-a-cookie-and-then-redirect-in-php)

Comment: Ah ok!, i thought without a Path it would be like a global Cookie. I will try this thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `if(isset($_COOKIE['login']) {` and `echo $_COOKIE['login'];`. For more reference, take a look at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Hope this helps!